First insulation layer on concrete walls
I'll be doing a bit of DIY and looking for other opinions.
The project is:

I have a basement room which is actually the garage.
Full concrete walls.
The property is quite old 1950's I think, so its fair to assume there is no outside insulation like vapor barriers or anything else.

Its not a living area, we just really use it as storage+car, but its the kind of place if we lay a rug or carpet on the floor, after a few weeks its humid and smelly, also get these kind of dark spots.
We don't actually see any mold, but I'm assuming its because its not a living area, it does create light mildew or damp.
So insulating from the concrete wall inwards:

layer 1: something expandable that covers all little spots and imperfections
layer 2: hard styroform xps 3cm all properly sealed with expandable foam spray
layer 3: 2 by 4 structure (no extra insulation)
layer 4: drywall (to finish)

My question is what would others out there rather go in layer 1:

expandable foam spray
e.g.: https://www.soudal.co.uk/pro/products/expanding-foam/1k-pu-foams/soudafoam-gap-filler-genius

or

an elastic coat
e.g.: https://www.soudal.co.uk/pro/products/coatings/waterproof-coatings/water-stop


It turns out "insolation" is a real thing, but it means "exposing to sunlight". Edited to what I think you were after. Thanks for showing me a new word!

You should apply the expanding foam if there no evidence of water seepage through the wall. The foam will act as an air barrier.
If you do the foam you should install batt insulation into the stud wall. It's cheaper and provides good insulating value for the purpose.
Because of the dampness, apply a 150mm wide polyethylene on top of the floor where the studs will be mounted.
Install any electrical.
For a vapour barrier, apply 6mil polyethylene across the face of the stud wall.
Apply your drywall.
For the floor, you should consider a subfloor system to allow circulation over the concrete and increase comfort.

There is no point on putting waterproofing on the inside of the wall to protect the inside from water outside.  The water will push the waterproofing away from the wall until it cracks and leaks.
There is little point in insulating a space unless you also condition it.  Heat it in winter.  Cool it in summer.  A dehumidifier would be sufficient cooling in summer for the typical basement.  If your furnace is in the basement, it probably provides sufficient heating.  If you don't have those things, then insulation is essentially useless.  Insulation slows heat transfer; it doesn't stop it nor does it add or remove heat.
Adding a dehumidifier is certainly DIY.  Adding heating may not be.  A 1500 watt resistance heater is DIY.  Hydronic radiant heat in the floor probably is not.
What you probably want to do is to fix your drainage.  Ideally you would do that outside (and you could add a vapor barrier at the same time).  That tends to be a lot of digging.  This is possible as a DIY project, but it's labor and time intensive.
It's possible to add drainage inside.  Gutters along the wall and trenches to a floor drain.  If you want to add drywall, the drainage would go behind the drywall.  It would be your layer 1.  This is more complex and less DIY than fixing it outside but no digging.
Note:  you would add drywall because you want drywall.  Drywall won't help with your mustiness except to hide it and allow it to fester behind the drywall.  So if you don't particularly want drywall, don't add it.  If you do want it, protect your new wall by putting a vapor barrier behind and under it.  But you'll still need drainage to let out any moisture that drips off the vapor barrier.
If it were me, the first thing that I'd try would be adding a dehumidifier.  Maybe that's enough in and of itself.  If not, you can always pursue larger projects.
